# Parent component to call child component function on a list of children component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

This is what I have right now.

[image]

Each row excluding reset button is a child component called `Item`. An item has a badge indicating its count, 2 buttons for increment, decrement & a `delete` button. The parent component called `ItemList` contains the reset button & the children. Since, the parent maintains list of children so delete functionality is also implemented in parent. All my required functionality is complete except for the `reset` button.

The reset button can be considered as a master button & should be able to reset the `count` of all children when clicked. Count is maintained as state by each child so ideally the parent should be calling the reset function of each child it contains in the list but I am unable to come up with a code for this particular portion. I am not sure how I can access the reset function of each child and apply it to all the children in the list.

**Code for Item (child)**

```
function Item({ deleteHandler }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [cName, setCName] = useState("badge bg-warning text-dark");

  useEffect(() => {
    setCName(count !== 0 ? "badge bg-primary" : "badge bg-warning text-dark");
  }, [count]);

  const increment = () => {
    setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
  };

  const decrement = () => {
    setCount((prevCount) => prevCount - 1);
  };
  
  //this is what needs to be called
  const reset = () => {
    setCount(0);
  };

  const zero = "zero";

  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}>
      <span style={{ marginRight: "10px" }} className={cName}>
        {count !== 0 ? count : zero}
      </span>
      <button
        style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}
        className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
        onClick={increment}
      >
        +
      </button>
      <button
        style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}
        className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
        onClick={decrement}
      >
        -
      </button>
      <button onClick={deleteHandler} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
        Delete
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Item;
```

**Code for ItemList (parent)**

```
function ItemList() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([Item, Item, Item]);

  const deleteItem = (index) => {
    alert(index);
    var temp = [...items]; //create new copy
    temp.splice(index, 1);
    setItems(temp);
  };

  const resetAll = () => {
    //this is where I need to call reset() on all the items (children)
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}>
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={resetAll}>
          Reset
        </button>
        {items.map((MyItem, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <MyItem deleteHandler={() => deleteItem(index)} />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ItemList;
```

Comment: Another approach is to use the state in the `ItemList` component as single source of truth. This eliminates the need for state in each Item component . https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-dust-3qc4k?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you *could* create a React ref and forward them to each child component, and implement the `useImperativeHandle` hook, this should only be a last resort. You may find this [Fully uncontrolled component with a key](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key) pattern useful.

It uses a React key to reset a component, which essentially unmounts/mounts a new "instance" to work with.

Add an additional piece of state to hold a `key` value, and update this state in the `resetAll` handler. I've used a random value, but any GUID generator or even a simple incremented counter would work, the key part being that a new React key value is used.

```
function ItemList() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([Item, Item, Item]);
  const [key, setKey] = useState(Math.random()); // <-- key state

  const deleteItem = (index) => {
    alert(index);
    var temp = [...items]; //create new copy
    temp.splice(index, 1);
    setItems(temp);
  };

  const resetAll = () => {
    setKey(Math.random()); // <-- update key state
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div key={key} style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}> // <-- resets elements/components
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={resetAll}>
          Reset
        </button>
        {items.map((MyItem, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <MyItem deleteHandler={() => deleteItem(index)} />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit parent-component-to-call-child-component-function-on-a-list-of-children-componen]

Comment: That's a very neat solution, I don't even need to rely on children for the reset. I knew that refs can do the job but didn't want to use such a bad approach.